# Grafana - How to order columns in Tables

Tags: grafana

## Is it possible to order the columns in a Grafana Table?

I have a Table *(sourced from InfluxDB)* but the columns are in a *«wrong»* order... I tried changing the order of the Group By clause in the InfluxQL but I get the exact same results.

Answer (score 31):

When you edit a table view,
Just next to Query tab (below the table), there is Transfer tab.
You can :

- hide using "filter by name"
- reorder using "organize fields"
  Works with 7.3.0

[image]

Comment: How to do in version 6.4

Comment: I'm not working with Grafana now, so cannot verify, but AFAIR (not sure, correct me please), it was not possible to do it in 6.
See comment below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65195200/3534621

Comment: Works in Grafana 9.3.6

Answer (score 5):

If you explicitly list the columns you want from InfluxDB they will be in that order in the table. If you use select * you don't have control.

The **time** column always comes back from InfluxDB as the first column. There is nothing you can do to control that (for now).

You can **hide** the column using a column style of hidden.

If you meant *rows* instead of *columns*, ask a new question.

Comment: Hi Frank,

All your cases work as you said, but do you have a solution for when the columns we want to sort come from a GROUP BY clause?

Comment: Can you change the order of the columns once you fill them in without destroying your whole query and starting over?  I added a dozen columns with various modifiers for a table, and now I want to add a new one at the beginning.  I can't figure out how to insert one at the beginning other than by switching to SQL (from which I cannot switch back).

Answer (score 5):

Using "Edit" option in your table, you can select "Transform" (arrow#1) and then hide a column by using the "eye" icon (arrow#2) and reorder table columns by grabbing the rectangular icon at each column (arrow#3) and move it up/down. Find those arrows in the image here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Column reordering is available since Grafana 7.0 via [organize fields](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transformations/types-options/#organize-fields) transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the same and found a solution.
So, when you use the built-in query and select '*' in field(value) it gives you all columns and as influxDB table columns (it will be returned in alphabetical order). But, I wanted my order to be different so I wrote a query which consisted of all the column tab names mentioned, separated by commas.

**So within the table panel - Metrics -> Click on button next to view symbol and choose (Edit Toggle mode) and enter your query.
 The query should look something like this -**

> SELECT "field_1","field_2","field_3","field_4"  FROM "autogen"."measurement_name" WHERE $timeFilter

you can probably write a script to help you create these scripts when you are entering data into your influxdb series.

Answer (score 0):

OK, So... this is a very hacky solution, but you can make multiple queries to get the results in the order you want.

Say you want want the order to be "field_2","field_3","field_1","field_4"

Query A can be SELECT "field_2","field_3" FROM "autogen"."measurement_name" WHERE $timeFilter

Query B can be SELECT "field_1","field_4" FROM "autogen"."measurement_name" WHERE $timeFilter

This works with prometheus, I have not tried with influx... but i don't see why it wouldnt work the same.